# PHP cURL Returning Failure

Tags: php, curl

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @ramraider for providing the solution.

**SOLUTION** ($field_string needed to include the original URL and also be passed corrected to the curl_setop()

```
//url-ify the data for the POST
$field_string = $url . http_build_query($fields, '', '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($field_string);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
```

I have a simple HTML webform that POSTS to a php file. In that PHP file is a simple cURL request. The issue is that their (the lead management company's server) keeps returning a 'failure' response. They are being ridiculously stingy on providing me with any reason as to why and won't provide any logs from their end so I can see where the process is failing. They even told me I need to use GET instead of POST which not only does their documentation **recommend** POST but GET did not work either. I've printed out as much debug information as I can to get an idea of where the issue is.

If I copy the submission $url and combine it with the $field_string result and submit it in my browser directly - it works! So, it has to be something in my code that is throwing it off but after two whole days of trying to research and figure it out on my own, I'm finally asking for help.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you kindly.

*Please note I left out some URL information for privacy reasons.*

**CODE:**

```
//extract data from the post
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://website.com/Import.aspx?';
$fields = array(
    'Provider'=> 'SabbaraWebsiteGET',
    'Client'=>'SabbaraGroup',
    'CampaignId'=>'1064',
    'first_name' => urlencode($_POST['first_name']),
    'last_name' => urlencode($_POST['last_name']),
    'user_email' => urlencode($_POST['email']),
    'phone' => urlencode($_POST['phone']),
    'current_payment' => urlencode($_POST['current_payment']),
    'type_loan' => urlencode($_POST['type_loan']),
    'reason_application' => urlencode($_POST['reason_application']),
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
$field_string = http_build_query($fields, '', '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($url);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

//execute post
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// DEBUGGING
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo '<pre>

Request Header:
'.curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ).'
'.$field_string.'

Response:
'.$response.'
</pre>';

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "\n\n" . 'Took '. $info['total_time']. ' seconds to send a request to '. $info['url']. ' CODE: '.$info['http_code']."\n";

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

**DEBUG RESPONSES FROM cURL**

```
Request Header:
POST /Import.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1147
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e7ceb9b6f9be238e


Provider=SabbaraWebsiteGET&Client=SabbaraGroup&CampaignId=1064&first_name=Test&last_name=Submission&user_email=test%2540test.com&phone=1234568547¤t_payment=151-300&type_loan=Federal%2BAnd%2BPrivate&reason_application=Credit%2BRepair

Response:
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=23zhmtzihv34bxc1abj2rbhu; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 21:31:29 GMT
Content-Length: 8

Failure 

Took 0.253105 seconds to send a request to https://website.com/Import.aspx? CODE: 200
```

Comment: Your code attempts to `url-ify` the data for sending using `$field_string` but you send `$fields` as the data - to my mind these yield different results as one sends data as `multipart/form-data` the other  as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so the host may be expecting a different content type header? Also I would suggest adding the `CAINFO` parameter to the curl request

Comment: Thank you so much! Your comment pointed my tired eyes in the right direction. I changed the code to the following:

'
//url-ify the data for the POST
$field_string = $url . http_build_query($fields, '', '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init($field_string);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
'

That did the trick! Also, thank you for your suggestion on adding CAINFO - I'm looking into that right now. Thank you again!

Comment: glad your tired eyes have had some relief